# Category not showing on frontend

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud, magento-2-commerce

I have created categories and products but not showing on frontend.

**Please note that I am working on Commerce cloud environment, so before marking this question as duplicate, or anything else consider this.**

Comment: try to do reindexing and clear the cache

Comment: I have already done the reindxing and cache clear etc..

Comment: Maybe you have created the categories in the same root where the default category was... moved out the categories and made them children of the default category, it should work.

Comment: No, It is permission issue in Magento commerce.I have fixed that myself. Thanks